# Getting python2 error in nodejs installation in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-20.04

I've updated to the new Ubuntu 20.04LTS version and all my node installations have gone. So to install node I have tried the following 2 methods:

1.sudo apt update

sudo apt install nodejs npm

2. curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt install nodejs

While installing nodejs I'm getting the error : nodejs : Depends: python2-minimal but it is not installable . Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thlKy.png)

Answer (score 3):

You need to install python2. Steps in Ubuntu 20

1. `sudo add-apt-repository universe`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install python2`
   This will install python2 successfully. Now you can continue with normal nodejs installation

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by following the instructions on https://speedysense.com/install-nodejs-on-ubuntu-20-04/

**Tldr** run these on a terminal: for current LTS Release (v14.x),

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Afterwards check your Nodejs and npm version by running these on a terminal:

```
node --version
npm --version
```